# How to bind the value of a NumericProperty to the Text of a Label?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

With Kivy, I understand we can use set the `text` of a label to a `StringProperty()` object, so whenever that string is updated, the label will automatically show the updated text.

My minimal example code, works fine, will show "apple" then "banana" one second later:

```
 #test.kv
<MyLabel>:
    font_size: 30
    text: self.examppleStringProperty

#test.py
class MyLabel(Label):
    examppleStringProperty = StringProperty("apple")

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt : self.runlater(), 1)

    def runlater(self):
        self.examppleStringProperty = "banana"

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self): return MyLabel()
```

Question: How do I do exactly the same, but for a Float? i.e have the label automatically update it's next, whenever the value of the Float is changed?

I have a module that updates a Float value with the current room temperature, which I would just like to show on a label in Kivy, but I'm not sure how to bind it "automagically".

I have tried `NumericProperty()`, but of course I can't set a `label.text` to a NumericProperty() object, as it is not a string.

For example, the following code does not work, simply never updates the label text to the number 42, because the `NumericProperty` isn't bound to the label text in anyway.

```
class MyLabel(Label):
    examppleStringProperty = StringProperty("apple")
    exampleNumericProperty = NumericProperty(0)

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        self.text = str(self.exampleNumericProperty)
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt : self.runlater(), 1)

    def runlater(self):
        self.exampleNumericProperty = 42

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self): return MyLabel()
```

Just looking for any good way to keep a Label *automatically* updated with the current value of a Float..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do it (Keep a label.text updated with the value of a Float), by using an "on_NumericProperty" function.

But I would appreciate any advice, if this is good or a bad design - or any suggested alternatives.

```
class MyLabel(Label):
    exampleStringProperty = StringProperty("no data yet")
    exampleNumericProperty = NumericProperty(0)

    def on_exampleNumericProperty(self, *args):
        self.exampleStringProperty = str(self.exampleNumericProperty)

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt : self.runlater(), 3)

    def runlater(self):
        self.exampleNumericProperty = 42

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self): return MyLabel()
```